# hadoop2 build hdfs without yarn and mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, build, hdfs

I want to make some changes to hadoop hdfs according to a published paper. After that I just need to build HDFS and get it running. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following Hadoop documentation

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you build on Linux.  If you use a different OS, you may need to do some extra steps; for details see [this](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/branch-2.3/BUILDING.txt) - I've never done this on non-Linux myself.

- Install Git, Java (JDK), Maven and ProtocolBuffer (2.5+ version required)
- Clone `https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common.git` by typing something like this in your command line:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common.git
  ```

  Note: you may want to use a particular branch corresponding to the version of HDFS you're looking to build.  To list all branches, type `git branch -a`.  Then to switch to branch 2.3, for example, type:

  ```
  git checkout --track origin/branch-2.3
  ```

  If you did everything correctly, you should see a message about tracking the remote branch you've selected.
- Make whatever changes you need to make in HDFS; the code lives under `hadoop-hdfs-project`.
- Compile the project by running the following from the root of your tree:

  ```
  mvn install -DskipTests
  ```

  This will take some time the first time you do it, but will be a lot quicker during re-runs.

Your final jars will be placed into directories like `hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target` (this is accurate for at least 2.3, but it might have been different in older version, or it may change in the future).

Comment: The solution you gave just compiles everything for the first time. I just want to compile and use hadoop HDFS, can I do that?